# How to suppress setting page headers by \thebibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, etoolbox

I'm modifying an existing template so I'm stuck to certain conditions.

`\documentclass` is `book`.
Bibliographies are managed by `cite` package and I cannot use `bibtex` nor `biblatex`. There are several commands manipulating the headings which I don't understand (they have been written by others):

```
\newcommand{\Author}[2]{\begin{center}\textbf{\large #1} \end{center} \medskip
            \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\raisebox{1mm}[\headheight][0pt]%
            {\vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\thepage \hfill\strut {\small #2}\hfill}\hrule}}} }

\newcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\raisebox{1mm}[\headheight][0pt]%
            {\vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\strut \hfill{\small #1}\hfill\thepage}\hrule}}} }
```

They seem to have no effect, but I'm afraid to change them.

The question is: how to suppress the text `REFERENCES` above the headrules which appears any time when I use `\thebibliography` environment? It would be ideal **not to clear** the hedings, but to **suppress any change** of headings done by `\thebibliography` environment.

I've tuned the bibliograpy caption design by doing

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
    {\chapter*}
    {\vmmshbibcaption}
    {}
    {}
```

where `\vmmshbibcaption` is a custom design command.

I've tried to do

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
    {\chaptermark}
    {}
    {}
    {}
```

but it had no effect.

If it matters, I have to support two different language-dependable captions of bibliography and I use

```
\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
}
```

MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{cite}


\newcommand{\vmmshbibcaption}[1]{
    \par\bigskip\centerline{\bf #1}\smallskip
}
% Setting the desired design for bibliographies
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\chapter*}
  {\vmmshbibcaption}
  {}
  {}

\makeatletter%{@}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\chaptermark}
  {}
  {}
  {}

\makeatother%{@}



\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\input diagxy

\begin{document}

\makeatletter%{@}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\begin{center}\large\uppercase{#1}\end{center}\par}

\newcommand{\Author}[2]{\begin{center}\textbf{\large #1} \end{center} \medskip
                \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\raisebox{1mm}[\headheight][0pt]%
                {\vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\thepage \hfill\strut {\small #2}\hfill}\hrule}}} }

\newcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\raisebox{1mm}[\headheight][0pt]%
                {\vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\strut \hfill{\small #1}\hfill\thepage}\hrule}}} }
\headsep=2mm

\newcommand{\l@abcd}[2]{{\begin{center}\par\medskip\normalsize\par\smallskip\noindent\hangindent5pt\hangafter=1{\bf #1}\end{center}}\par\medskip}

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\parindent}
                    {3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}{\bf\centering}}
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{\small\leftskip0pt\par\noindent\hangindent27pt\hangafter=1{\qquad#1} \dotfill~~#2\par}

\renewcommand{\l@part}[2]{\normalsize\leftskip0pt\par\smallskip\noindent\hangindent17pt\hangafter=1{\bf #1} \normalsize\dotfill~~#2\smallskip\par}

\makeatother%@

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
}

\Title{THESIS CAPTION} % обязательное поле!
%
% Авторы

\Author{Smith J.}


\cite{A01}, \cite{A02}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{A01} Book 1
    \bibitem{A02} Book 2
\end{thebibliography}

\cite{b01}, \cite{A01}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{b01} Book 1
    \bibitem{b02} Book 2
\end{thebibliography}
\clearpage
kkk
\clearpage
kkk

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Does `\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\bibname{}
}` instead of `\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
}` do the job?  2. From my point of view the `\Author` and `shorttitle` are unrelated to your problem, so you could minimime your question code.

Comment: 1. Yes, it does, thank you! But it also removes the `References` caption from the body of the document. Is that effect avoidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. I used `\meaning\thebibliography` to get the definition of the beginning of `thebibliography` environment and found `\@mkboth` command there. So, I patched `\thebibliography` command with `etoolbox` package. Note that I needed a dummy command `\vmmshnothing`: otherwise the text `References` was just printed twice in the beginning of the bibliography.

```
\makeatletter%{@}

\newcommand{\vmmshnothing}[2]{}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
    {\@mkboth}
    {\vmmshnothing}
    {}
    {}

\makeatother%{@}
```

Comment: For those interested also in making `thebibliography` title look like a section title instead of chapter title: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532045/28685