# Change the sectioning level created by `thebibliography` environment

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

I use the environment `thebibliograghy` for a document of the **`book` class**, but I'd like to have a bibliography title formatted like a `section` title (no page clearing, for example) instead of a `chapter` title (the book is a collection of papers each one being a chapter and having its own bibliography).

Can `thebibliography` environment be changed so to create a title formatted like the one of a `section` instead of `chapter`?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a bibliography like a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/how-can-i-create-a-bibliography-like-a-section)

Comment: The question marked as duplicate uses the `article` document class.  Treating the bibliography as `\section*` will format it in the desired manner, but will include it (incorrectly) in the current chapter.  Even if `\clearpage` is used, there will be a running head left over from that chapter.  To correct that, `\markboth{Bibliography}{Bibliography}` can be entered after `\clearpage`.

Comment: @DG' That question is very different because deals with article class, and it's just asking how the convert the `thebibliography`, which is already formatted as a section, from unnumbered to numbered. However the solution, even though does not answer directly my question, can be adapted to. In fact `\usepackage{etoolbox} \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}` make thebibliography environment look like a section in book class. I think the question should be reopened, and answered for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, in a `book` class document you can make the title of `thebibliography` environment look like a *section* (instead of *chapter*) title by adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution makes `thebibliography` *look like* a section, but in some cases, like if you print the chapter title in the header, "REFERENCES" will replace the chapter title in bibliography pages. Any idea on how to avoid this?